# Ruby on Rails - Scope with Join and Order

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, scope

I have 2 classes:

```
class Solution
  has_many :solution_votes

class SolutionVote
  belongs_to :solution
```

I have something like this in my views:

```
    Proposed Solution A - 2 votes up - 5 votes down
    Proposed Solution B - 1 vote up  - 0 votes down
    Proposed Solution C - 0 votes up - 0 votes down
    Proposed Solution D - 7 votes up - 2 votes down
    Proposed Solution E - 3 votes up - 1 vote down
```

What I would like is to sort this by the most UP votes so that it looks like this instead:

```
    Proposed Solution D - 7 votes up - 2 votes down
    Proposed Solution E - 3 votes up - 1 vote down
    Proposed Solution A - 2 votes up - 5 votes down
    Proposed Solution B - 1 vote up  - 0 votes down
    Proposed Solution C - 0 votes up - 0 votes down
```

I have this so far:

```
 scope :most_votes_up,
  select("solutions.*, count(solution_votes.id) AS votes_count").
      where(['solutions.state = ?', 'Proposed']).
      joins(:solution_votes).
      group("solutions.id").
      order("votes_count DESC")
```

which produces this output:

```
    Proposed Solution D - 7 votes up - 2 votes down
    Proposed Solution A - 2 votes up - 5 votes down
    Proposed Solution E - 3 votes up - 1 vote down
    Proposed Solution B - 1 vote up  - 0 votes down
```

BUT... the issues I'm still having are:
1.  The proposed solutions with no votes are missing (Proposed Solution C in the example above is missing from the displayed list)
2.  How do I specify a count on only the UP votes (right now, it's ordering based on which proposed solution got the MOST votes (both up and down), and not just up)?

I'm using PostGRESQL

Comment: I just realized why my 0 votes are not appearing in the view: because I don't yet have a record for them in the solutions_vote table.  So, what do I do?  I still need them to appear in the view.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Use a left join (instead of the default inner join) to include the solutions with 0 associated solution_votes.
2. You can simply include only up votes in the count.

Here's how I'd revise the scope:

```
select("solutions.*, count(solution_votes.id) AS votes_count").
  joins("left join solution_votes on solution_votes.solution_id = solutions.id").
  where(['solutions.state = ? and solution_votes.direction = ?', 'Proposed', 'up']).
  group("solutions.id").
  order("votes_count DESC")
```

This makes a few assumptions about your column names, but you should be able to tailor it to your actual schema without much trouble. I also put `joins` before `where` - this won't technically make a difference, but it's the order SQL would require, and it makes more logical sense to me.

Edit: 
It sounds as though you want to keep votes_count as the count of all the votes, but still sort by the number of up votes. I'm not sure why that would be unless you're calling `.votes_count` on the returned Solution objects, but it is possible. In order to do this, you switch from the `count` aggregation to `sum`, and then do something that treats records matching the condition you want to count as 1, and those not matching as 0. Two ways present themselves, a `case` expression, like `sum(case when solution_votes.direction = 'up' then 1 else 0 end)`, or doing some creative casting to convert booleans to integers, e.g. `sum(cast(solution_votes.direction = 'up' as integer))`. Both of these will work - the sum will be the total number of up votes, which you can then use in the order clause. Selecting the first, for no particular reason, we end up with the following revised scope:

```
select("solutions.*, count(solution_votes.id) AS votes_count, sum(case when solution_votes.direction = 'up' then 1 else 0 end) as up_votes").
  joins("left join solution_votes on solution_votes.solution_id = solutions.id").
  where(['solutions.state = ? and solution_votes.direction = ?', 'Proposed', 'up']).
  group("solutions.id").
  order("up_votes DESC")
```

Comment: Thanks for this! - this solves 1 of 2 of my issues:  with the left join, now even the 0 votes show up.  However, I'm still having an issue with ALL the votes showing up, just sorted by the UP votes.  Your code will only return the UP votes, while I need ALL votes returned.

Comment: What do you mean by 'returned' and 'show up'? Given that this is Rails, what's going to be returned is a collection of Solution objects. The scope just determines which ones you get and what order they're in.

Comment: Thank you again.  This is what I was missing.  I modified it slightly to what return all the votes (not just up votes) but that was easy after your help:    scope :most_votes_up,
        select("solutions.*, count(solution_votes.id) AS votes_count, sum(case when solution_votes.vote = 'up' then 1 else 0 end) as up_votes").
            joins("left join solution_votes on solution_votes.solution_id = solutions.id").
            where(['solutions.state = ?', 'Proposed']).
            group("solutions.id").
            order("up_votes DESC")